# How to get Variable in Variable (%var1%var2%%)

Tags: variables, batch-file, set

I'm trying to get a String of an users input and then let the Text scroll.

What I have so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set /p myString=String:
cls

call :StringLenght result myString
:ECHO
set /a result=%result%-1
set myString=%mystring:~%result%%
echo %myString%
ping -n 2 localhost>nul
cls

:StringLenght <resultVar> <stringVar>
(   
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "s=!%~2!#"
    set "len=0"
    for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
        if "!s:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
            set /a "len+=%%P"
            set "s=!s:~%%P!"
        )
    )
)
( 
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%len%"
    goto ECHO
)
```

Now at this Point it doesn't works:

```
set myString=%mystring:~%result%%
```

I can't get the String out of a variable when I'm in a variable %% (Sounds weird but I think you can imagine what I mean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need delayed expansion for this to work.

Here is the concept:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "mystring=mousetail"
set result=5
echo %mystring%
echo !mystring:~%result%!
```

Should be easy to implement into your code.

Comment: So I dont need an "endlocal"? - Thanks for the Code that works for me :)

Comment: `endlocal` is done implicite, when the Batch file ends. You may give it an `endlocal`, but it's not really needed. (except you have to toggle it on and off during the batchfile - sometimes, you'll have to).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without delayed expansion is to use the `call` command like this:

```
@echo off

set "myString=something"
set "result=4"
echo %myString%
call echo %%myString:~%result%%%
```

What happens is that the expansion of `Result` is done immediately but the expansion of `myString` is carried out to the new `cmd` instance opened by `call`:

- firstly, the `%%` after `echo` is replaced by a single `%`;
- secondly, `%result%` is expanded, that is, replaced by its value `4`;
- thirdly, the last `%%` is replaced by a single `%`;
- and lastly, the command line `echo %myString:~4%` is passed over to the new `cmd` instance opened by `call`, thus `thing` is displayed;

Notice, that this only works in a batch file but not in command prompt (`cmd`) directly.

---

In case you need delayed expansion for both nested variables, you could use a `for` loop:

```
@echo off

set "myString=something"
set "result=4"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !myString!
for %%I in (!Result!) do echo !myString:~%%I!
endlocal
```

This works because the `for` variable `%%I` is expanded before delayed expansion is applied, so the loop body receives the command line `echo !myString:~4!`.